# supress NULL output from an if statement inside a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a matrix of values using replicate(), but when the if() statement returns a NULL, that creates a list instead of a matrix.  I've spent time reading web pages and Questions here but just can't seem to get something that works.  I've tried variations on invisible and sink, but still haven't been able to get an output that doesn't return a NULL value.

Here is an example that gives a NULL value for the 5th entry.
How do I get the if() statement to not return anything, including NULL?

```
set.seed(10)
reps <- 10

f_myfun2 <- function(i){
  x1 <- rep(1:4, each=5)
  x2 <- rep(1:5, times=4)
  n <- length(x1)
  y <- 0.20 + 0.30*x1 + 0.7*x2 + 0.50*rnorm(n)
  cis <- confint(lm( y ~ x1*x2 ))
  int_lower <- cis[4,1]
  int_upper <- cis[4,2]
  if(int_lower > 0 | int_upper < 0){
    # I don't want to return anything, including a NULL value
    # tried various things including invisible, sink, etc
  }
  else{
    cis2 <- confint(lm( y ~ x1 + x2))
    c(cis2[2,], cis2[3,])
  }
}


sims <- replicate(reps, f_myfun2(1))
sims  # [[5]] is NULL rather than just missing
str(sims) # now it's a list rather than a matrix without the NULL
is(sims)
```

Comment: All R functions return something. The ones that look like they return nothing just return their value's invisibly. You can put `return(invisible(NULL))` in your `if` branch to exit the function "silently". You will still need to filter those out after the replicate. The `replicate` command will always returns a collection with a dimension equal to the number of requested replications. `do.call("rbind", Filter(function(x) !is.null(x), sims))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your final goal is to combine all of them into one dataframe/matrix you don't have to worry about those `NULL` values when you combine they are automatically removed.

```
set.seed(10)
sims <- replicate(reps, f_myfun2(1))
result <- do.call(rbind, sims)
result
#            2.5 %    97.5 %     2.5 %    97.5 %
# [1,]  0.26428935 0.5953288 0.5766971 0.8384067
# [2,]  0.20815417 0.5763875 0.5750148 0.8661288
# [3,]  0.16616864 0.5437533 0.5694641 0.8679710
# [4,]  0.05366132 0.5055326 0.5076891 0.8649247
# [5,]  0.26292580 0.6246576 0.6441824 0.9301565
# [6,]  0.21173249 0.5972766 0.5297051 0.8345045
# [7,] -0.01499442 0.5077043 0.5399975 0.9532272
# [8,]  0.23639931 0.5871463 0.5270991 0.8043890
# [9,] -0.09686737 0.2529322 0.4378804 0.7144212
```

Comment: I accepted and upvoted, but upvote doesn't register because I have < 15 reputation.